# Estimating the average of two gaussians' mean

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, estimation-theory

Assume that $X\sim \mathcal N(\sigma_1,\mu_1)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal N(\sigma_2,\mu_2)$.

I want to estimate $\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$ after observing $X,Y$.

In my setting, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are known and we want to estimate the average of the means (e.g., what is the MLE of it?).

---

In the special case where we know that $\mu=\mu_1=\mu_2$ (i.e., we estimate the same quantity from observations with different variances), [it is known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.11537.pdf) that the MLE is:

$$
X\cdot \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} + Y\cdot \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}.
$$

How does this generalize to arbitrary $\mu_1,\mu_2$?

Comment: In standard usage, $\operatorname N(a,b)$ or $\mathcal N(a,b)$ means normal with EXPECTED VALUE $a$ and VARIANCE $b. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ is $(X,Y)$. So, by the [functional invariance of the MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance) (that is, simply by definition), the MLE of $g(\mu_1,\mu_2):=(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$ is $g(X,Y):=(X+Y)/2$, which also, obviously, maximizes the [profile likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Profile_likelihood)
$$L_{X,Y}(\mu):=\sup\{L_{X,Y}(\mu_1,\mu_2)\colon(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2=\mu\}$$
in $\mu$, where $L_{X,Y}(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ is the likelihood.

---

One may note that the MLE $(X+Y)/2$ of $(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$ does not depend on $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$.

Comment: You're right, and the MLE probably doesn't capture what I intended (but that's the closest thing I have found).

I have some difficulty phrasing the question; what I ultimately want to estimate $\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$ in a way that would minimize the expected squared error with respect to the drawing of $X,Y$.

Comment: To put it differently: I want a method for estimating the average so that if we run it many times (drawing different $X,Y$ each time) it would minimize the expected squared error.

Comment: @RB : The estimator $(X+Y)/2$ is also the only unbiased linear estimator (of the form $aX+bY$) of $(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$. Moreover, this estimator is the minimax linear estimator of $(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$ with respect to the quadratic loss function. However, all that is for another question. To keep things in good order, you may want to post such "expected squared error" questions separately.

Comment: Thanks again. I am not necessarily interested in unbiased estimates (i.e., I expect the estimate to be closer to $X$, if $\sigma_1<\sigma_2$, and vice versa). I will ask a separate question.

Comment: "Invariance" is a frequently used misnomer for this. It's actually equivariance.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Of course. Thank you for your comment. One can say: defined by the equivariance.